# Finding the maximum combined total in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, set, mathematical-optimization

Suppose you had a set of numbers like below:

```
[A,B,C]

[6, 4.5, 6]
[7, 6, 5]
[9, 4.5, 6]
```

Only one number from each set **AND** of a category (A, B, or C) may be used to find the greatest sum. In this case, A=9, B=6, and C=6 will produce the greatest sum of 21. The greatest sum cannot be 22 (9+7+6) because 9 and 7 conflict by both being category A.

How can I do this in Java?

I am having trouble finding the largest sum because picking the largest value in each category does not guarantee the largest sum. Some categories may be forced into smaller values decreasing the sum. Remember that only one number from each set AND of a category may be chosen.

Comment: Seems like finding the largest number in every column and add them... so what have you tried?

Comment: What specifically is the question? You have to write code, in Java, using a loop, comparing numbers and adding a result.

Comment: I am having trouble finding the maximum because picking the largest value in each category does not guarantee the largest sum. Some categories may be forced into smaller values decreasing the sum. Remember that only one number from each set AND of a category may be chosen.

Comment: This looks equivalent to http://projecteuler.net/problem=345

Comment: +1 - This is a perfectly reasonable question if you actually take the time to read it.  I'm not sure why people are giving this user flak.

Comment: You may find that you'll get some more esoteric (read efficient) answers if you ask this on http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're still having trouble, I'd recommend reposting.  You'll get a better response if you include an attempt (in Java), it doesn't matter if it's wrong, people want to see you've made the effort because SO gets a lot 'do this for me' requests. If you haven't tried yet, start with this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_first_search - and ask questions as they come up. @BrianJ's answer, while incorrect, references the 8-queens problem which should be a similar implementation

Comment: I found out that the Hungarian algorithm may help me solve this problem. However, this algorithm searches for the lowest cost. Can anyone teach me how to find the maximum sum with this algorithm?

Comment: @user1584575 Customary in optimization when striving to maximize an objective function with a minimization method, is to simply negate the objective function and minimize it. In your case you would thus _minimize_ `-sum`. Is this implementable?

Comment: @user1584575 - Yep, you could use this algorithm, but this is a difficult one to understand.  Try doing the problem by hand and then writing it in code.  You may need to understand recursion to solve this, this is why I recommend looking at depth first search.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like the [Eight Queens Puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle), where you have to place 8 queens on a chessboard without any of them in the path of another. (If you don't know chess, don't fret over the analogy).

Suppose your example array:

```
[6, 4.5, 6]
[7,   6, 5]
[9, 4.5, 6]
```

Find the largest value overall (in this case 9), and block out its column and row.

Your new array looks like this (with x's as choices no longer valid).

```
[x, 4.5, 6]
[x,   6, 5]
[x,   x, x]
```

Repeat that process over and over until you have chosen one value from each column and each row.

Now, as a warning, having multiple locations for the current max (as in the second step of the example, with the two 6s) leads to some more conditions. I will leave some of the fun with you, but will gladly give more help if it is needed.

***Warning***

This answer is not valid, as pointed out by Neil C. in the comments.
Specific counterexample:

```
[10, 9, 1]
[ 9, 1, 1]
[ 1, 1, 1]
```

I don't have the fix at hand yet, but I want to leave this answer available for help in coming up with the correct solution.

Comment: This algorithm won't always work: consider the array `{ { 10, 9, 1 }, { 9, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 } }` where this algorithm gives `10 + 1 + 1 = 12` as the output, but the result should be `9 + 9 + 1 = 19`

Comment: @Niall C. I see your point. I will have to think about it some more. Thanks for the counter example.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to brute-force search this is to generate all permutations of length N where N is the number of categories.  Then, for each permutation, calculate the sum of `Matrix[i][Permutation[i]]` for all i and take the maximum.

Answer (score -2):

Here's some ideas about how I would do it.

let's say you store your data in a 2d array of integers

```
int [] [] data = new int [rows] [columns]
```

so in this case columns are A, B, C etc.

You need to iterate like this when searching the maximum:

`data[i][fix]` so the column is fixed and the row is changed in the loop

in your example if you want to get the max of `A` and you use a 2d array like i advised, then:

```
int [] [] data = new int [3][3];
```

then the set where you need to get the maximum for `A` from is `data [0][0]`, `data[1][0]` and `data[2][0]`

EDIT:

Here's one possible solution for you.

```
//here is our data array.
int [][] data = new int[3][];

//fill up with som random data
data[0] = new int[]{10,20,4,5,56,87,9};
data[1] = new int[]{1,65,0,10,3};
data[2] = new int[]{34,5,6,67,3,54};

//get the biggest arrays length
int maxArrayLength = 0;
for(int i=1; i<data.length; i++)
{
    if(data[i].length > data[maxArrayLength].length)
        maxArrayLength = i;
}
maxArrayLength = data[maxArrayLength].length;

//collect the max in each category
int [] categoryMax = new int[maxArrayLength];

//loop through the categories
for(int i=0; i<maxArrayLength; i++)
{
    //in each iteration we get a winner
    int categoryWinner = 0;

    // now loop through the values of the current category
    for(int j=0; j<data.length; j++)
    {
        int [] actualArray = data[j];
        int [] winnerArray = data[categoryWinner];

        //check if we are in the bounds, if so, then perform a simple maxsearch
        if(i<actualArray.length)
            if(actualArray[i] > winnerArray[i])
            categoryWinner = j;
    }

    //set the current element of the winners array.
    categoryMax [i] = data[categoryWinner][i];
}

int sum = 0;

// we are ready, print it out!
for(int i=0; i<categoryMax.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println((i+1) + ". groups winner: " + categoryMax[i]);
    sum+=categoryMax[i];
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Actually, it's not my homework. I'm just trying to figure out how to find the maximum. It was easy just going through and finding the largest value in each set.

However, suppose one category had larger value in a later set, I couldn't figure out how to go back and re-do the calculation again. Also, if I changed a category to the largest value, it doesn't guarantee that I will get the largest sum. Another category may be forced to a lower value.

Comment: Oh, then you can always check, if you are out of values by the arrays .length attribute

Comment: I don't understand. How does arrays.length help me find the maximum?

Comment: It only helps you while in the middle of a loop realizing, if you are out of the arrays bound or not. So you have a problem implementing a maxsearch?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the maximum sum on the condition that I can only pick one number from each set under one category. If this sounds like a maxsearch, that may be what I am looking for.

Comment: I wrote you one possible solution, take a look!

Comment: It works wonderfully finding the largest value of each array. The tricky part is eliminating the large values already selected in a category. I'm still having trouble with that.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the OPs original problem at all